# Minimum value of a differentiable function at some point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be differentiable for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and let $f(0)=2$ and $f^\prime(x)\leq -2$.

How could i find the minimum value of $f(-1).$

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply mean value theorem to get a $c$ between $0$ and $-1$ and  $$f(0)-f(-1)=f'(c)(0-(-1))\le -2 \implies 4\le f(-1)$$

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the minimum is achieved for $f(x)=2-2x$, in which case $f(-1)=2+2=4$. To see it can't be lower, use the mean value theorem, which says
$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(-1)-f(0)}{-1-0}=f(0)-f(-1)>2-4=-2$$
for some $\xi\in(-1,0)$ if it's lower.

Answer (score 1):

What is the fastest rate at which $f$ can decrease? At a rate of $f'(x) = -2$. That being the case, what is the equation for $f$?

Comment: i will be grateful if you extend your answer a little bit.

Comment: user2345215 has written it out above. If $f'(x) = -2$, then $f$ is a straight line of slope $-2$; as it passes through $(0,2)$, the equation is $f(x) = 2 - 2x$.